# Scala public becomes private when accessed from Java?

Tags: java, scala, maven, scala-java-interop

I am quite familiar with *Java* and *Maven*, but not at all with *Scala*. I am trying to access *Scala* from *Java* and one of the problems I can't seem to understand is the following:

### My Question

In `AccessScala.java` I try to access a variable in `WithinModule.scala`:

```java
package me.parent.jModule;

public class AccessScala{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WithinModule within = new WithinModule();
        // -- this is like a static variable
        System.out.println(WithinModule.string);
        // -- this is like an instance variable
        System.out.println(within.string);
        // -- this is a getter, as it should be in Java
        System.out.println(within.getString());
    }
}
```

This variable [should be public](https://www.jesperdj.com/2016/01/08/scala-access-modifiers-and-qualifiers-in-detail/)

```scala
package me.parent.jModule;

class WithinModule{
  val string : String = "this is the local scala string";
}
```

But when running `mvn clean package` it tells me this variable is private:

```
[ERROR] [Error] C:\projectLocation\parent\jModule\src\main\java\me\parent\jModule\AccessScala.java:7: string has private access in me.parent.jModule.WithinModule
[ERROR] [Error] C:\projectLocation\parent\jModule\src\main\java\me\parent\jModule\AccessScala.java:9: string has private access in me.parent.jModule.WithinModule
```

Basically, am I misunderstanding how this should work, or am I doing something wrong?

### Project Setup

I put the project up on [GitHub](https://github.com/SonkeWohler/parent), with a summary of what may be relevant here. The files are organised like so

```
> parent
 | > jModule
 | | > src/main
 | | | > java/me/parent/jModule
 | | | | > AccessScala.java
 | | | > scala/me/parent/jModule
 | | | | > WithinModule.scala
 | | > pom.xml
 | > sModule
 | | > src/scala/me/parent/sModule
 | | | >ExternalModule.scala
 | | > pom.xml
 | > pom.xml
```

I took my parent `pom.xml` mostly from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/scala-in-java-maven-project). With some modifications it ended up like below. This exact setup works fine on another project where there was (so far) only one case where *Java* was making use of a class written in *Scala*, but plenty of code in both languages. Testing and all worked fine, until we tried to access `val`s from *Scala* within *Java*.

I use the Maven *compiler*, *surefire* and *failsafe* plugins to compile and test Java (no tests yet) and the *Scala-Maven* and *ScalaTest* plugins to compile and test Scala code (also no tests yet). They are configured to compile and test Scala first, then move on to Java.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>me</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- stuff for compiling and testing Java during `mvn package` -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- This is for Scala compilation during `mvn package` -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!--
            <execution>
              <id>scala-test-compile</id>
              <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            -->
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>jModule</module>
        <module>sModule</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

### PS

Any suggestions what is going on would be appreciated. As I mentioned I'm trying to make Java and Scala work together, which I hear should be quite easy, but I keep running into issues, this is one of them.

Comment: Scala creates `string()` method which acts as an accessor for your `string` property which is still private. So, if you want to use it in Java, just call `string()`

Comment: Calling Java from Scala is reasonably simple (with `JavaConverters` package) but going the other way is typically more difficult for the reasons outlined in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analysing `scalac -print` output we see that

```
class WithinModule {
  val string : String = "this is the local scala string"
}
```

expands to something like

```
  class iw$WithinModule extends Object {
    private[this] val string: String = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def string(): String = iw$WithinModule.this.string;
    def <init>(): $line184.iw$WithinModule = {
      iw$WithinModule.super.<init>();
      iw$WithinModule.this.string = "this is the local scala string";
      ()
    }
  }
```

where we note `def string(): String`, therefore in `AccessScala.java` try

```
WithinModule within = new WithinModule();
System.out.println(within.string());
```